# Make makefile executable

Tags: c, makefile

So, I've built my makefile and it works well, but I still need to type ./escalunador (My program name) to run it, how do I include that in my makefile?

```
CC = gcc  
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c99

all: escalunador

escalunador: escalunador.o usables.o queue.o linkedlist.o  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o escalunador escalunador.o usables.o queue.o linkedlist.o

escalunador.o: escalunador.c usables.h queue.h linkedlist.h  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c escalunador.c

usables.o: usables.c queue.h linkedlist.h  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c usables.c

queue.o: queue.c linkedlist.h  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c queue.c

linkedlist.o: linkedlist.c linkedlist.h  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c linkedlist.c

clean:   
    $(RM) escalunador *.p *~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
run: escalunador
  ./escalunador

.PHONY: run
```

And maybe you want to modify `all: ./escalunador` to `all: run`.

Comment: I fell dumb now ahah, thanks for your answear, it worked!

Comment: And thanks for the edit too, it was my first post here :)